# Google Analytics Event Not Tracking

Tags: javascript, google-analytics

I cannot get Google Analytics to track events. Code is below. I have tried hitCallback function and can confirm Google is receiving and responding but not recording!

I have a Goal set up with a 'Basket' category (equal to) and an event named 'Added To Basket' (equal to) with same capitalisation.

Have I missed something?

[image]

Comment: Have you checked in real time reports or GA Debugger tool to see if you see the hit?

Comment: @nyuen Do you mean real time reports in analytics? Didn't even know a GA debugger existed! Googled and found a Chrome extension. Will check and report back here. Thanks

Comment: Yes, install the debugger and trigger the event and if all is well, then you should be able to see the activity of sending the hit in to Google.

Comment: Just tested the with the GA debugger. I can see that the command is run but still nothing in analytics. Tested real time reports as well. I could see my visit but no real time events.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Managed to work it out after a lot of testing. The last parameter in the `ga();` function is an integer not a decimal. My above example code does not due to the last parameter being `9.99`, it should be a whole number.